# Nomenclature of an Alkane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Is the correct name for the following structure 3-tert-butylhexane or 3-ethyl-2,2-dimethylhexane?

I think it is 3-tert-butylhexane, but the textbook says it is 3-ethyl-2,2-dimethylhexane. Can someone please explain?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to IUPAC ([source](http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm)):

> 2.6 - If chains of equal length are competing for selection as main chain in a saturated branched acyclic hydrocarbon, then the choice goes in series to:
>   
> (a) The chain which has the greatest number of side chains.

Therefore the correct name is 3-ethyl-2,2-dimethylhexane as opposed to 3-*tert*-butylhexane because the former has more side chains.

Comment: So straight chain parent groups aren't necessarily favored and this rule always dominates?

Comment: The parent name is always a straight chain (hexane in this example). The source I gave has the full list of rules for naming if you are still confused.

Comment: That makes sense. I did more practice problems and have understood nomenclature a little better. Thanks for your help.